# I can't send data to a fragment from an activity with broadcast

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, navigationview

I'm trying to send data from a an activity to a fragment.The data is the name of the item witch is currently clicked, I needed because I want to make a query.But the data is never sent. I also tried to send the broadcast before calling fragment.begingTrascation, but still doesn't worked,
I also changed the name of the constants but still, the broadcast from the Fragment is never triggered.
I don't know why is not working, what can I do to solve this?

```
    private NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationListener = new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_today) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new TodayFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_inbox) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new InboxFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_add_list) {
            ListBottomSheet bottomSheet = new ListBottomSheet();
            bottomSheet.showNow(getSupportFragmentManager(), "bottomSheetList");

        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_account) {
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeDrawerActivity.this, AccountActivity.class));

        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_random_task) {
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeDrawerActivity.this, RandomTaskActivity.class));

        } else {
            /* one of the list items
              was clicked therefore
              get the data form db
             */
            item.setCheckable(true);
            item.setChecked(true);
            String listName = item.getTitle().toString();
            Toast.makeText(HomeDrawerActivity.this, listName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            /* create the fragment */

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ListFragment())
                    .commit();

            /* send data to the fragment */

            Intent intent = new Intent(LIST_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_LIST_NAME, listName);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(HomeDrawerActivity.this).sendBroadcast(intent);

        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
};

public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
private Context context;
private String documentName;

private ListAdaptor listAdaptor;
private RecyclerView recyclerViewList;

private ColorDrawable swipeBackgroundRight = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
private ColorDrawable swipeBackgroundLeft = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1E88E5"));

private Drawable iconDelete;
private Drawable iconComplete;

private SoundPool soundPool;
private int soundId;

private FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference collectionReference = firestore.collection("Users")
        .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
        .collection("Lists");

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
            .registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(HomeDrawerActivity.LIST_ACTION));


    iconDelete = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_delete);
    iconComplete = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_completed);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(documentName)) {
        collectionReference.document(documentName);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

     /* create the option query
        for the recycler
      */

    Query query = collectionReference;

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Task> options =
            new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Task>()
                    .setQuery(query, Task.class)
                    .build();

    listAdaptor = new ListAdaptor(options);

    recyclerViewList = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
    recyclerViewList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerViewList.setAdapter(listAdaptor);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes =
                new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .build();

        soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(1)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build();

    } else {
        soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0);
    }
    soundId = soundPool.load(getActivity(), R.raw.completed, 1);

    new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                listAdaptor.delete(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                Toast.makeText(context, "Task deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                listAdaptor.update(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

                soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);

                Toast.makeText(context, "Task completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                swipeBackgroundRight.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                iconDelete.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

            View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
            int iconMargin = (itemView.getHeight() - iconDelete.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2;
            if (dX > 0) {
                swipeBackgroundRight.setBounds(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(), (int) dX, itemView.getBottom());
                iconDelete.setBounds(itemView.getLeft() + iconMargin, itemView.getTop() + iconMargin, itemView.getLeft() + iconMargin + iconDelete.getIntrinsicWidth(), itemView.getBottom() - iconMargin);
            } else if (dX < 0) {
                swipeBackgroundLeft.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + (int) dX, itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
                iconComplete.setBounds(itemView.getRight() - iconMargin - iconComplete.getIntrinsicWidth(), itemView.getTop() + iconMargin, itemView.getRight() - iconMargin,
                        itemView.getBottom() - iconMargin);

            } else {
                swipeBackgroundLeft.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                swipeBackgroundRight.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

            }
            c.save();

            swipeBackgroundRight.draw(c);
            swipeBackgroundLeft.draw(c);
            if (dX > 0) {
                c.clipRect(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(), (int) dX, itemView.getBottom());
            } else {
                c.clipRect(itemView.getRight() + (int) dX, itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
            }

            iconDelete.draw(c);
            iconComplete.draw(c);
            c.restore();


            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewList);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (HomeDrawerActivity.LIST_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            /* get the data from db */

            documentName = intent.getStringExtra(HomeDrawerActivity.KEY_LIST_NAME);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "List fragment" + documentName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    listAdaptor.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send a broadcast before the `Fragment` transaction is started, it is very likely that the `Fragment` will not manage to set up its `BroadcastReceiver` in time to catch the transmission.

But in your case, you can add the data you want to pass to the `Fragment` to the arguments `Bundle` of the `ListFragment` instance before starting the transaction:

```
String listName = item.getTitle().toString();

/* create the fragment */
ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();

/* store data in arguments Bundle */
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(KEY_LIST_NAME, listName);
listFragment.setArguments(args);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, listFragment )
                .commit();
```

In `ListFragment`, you can access the data as follows:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    String listName = args.getString(KEY_LIST_NAME);

    // ....
}
```

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @Scepticul - did you use listFragment.setArguments(args); before starting the transaction?

Comment: Yes, exactly like in your example.

Comment: @Scepticul - thanks for letting me know and good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you, again!